# How to get object reference from selector for C3 JS charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I'm using [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) for graphing and everything is working as expected.

However, I'd like to access the API from other scripts, that is call `resize` etc...

if I use:

```
var chart = c3.generate({ ... });
```

I can then access the chart object and it's API like:

```
chart.resize();
```

However, if I do not have access to the chart object as it's another script I can get the HTML DOM element (using jQuery):

```
$(".c3").each(function(i, chart) { 
    // Here I want to do something like chart.resize();
    // But chart is just the DOM reference, not the chart variable
    // I need something like c3.get(chart)????
});
```

But `chart` in the loop is a DOM object, not the `var chart` made from `c3.generate`.

Any ideas how I can get this object? The documentation isn't quite finished ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you're already using jQuery, here's a solution using [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):

Save a reference to the chart, keyed on its DOM element:

```
var selector = '#some-selector';
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindTo: selector,
  // ...
});

$(selector).data('c3-chart', chart);
```

To access the chart for each `.c3` element:

```
$('.c3').each(function() {
  var chart = $(this).data('c3-chart'); 
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, jQuery always has these useful gems!

Comment: @RemarkLima this is not working for me, I still get a DOM element

Comment: Are you adding the chart object to the data? Make sure it's not the selector being added...